# ¿Como cambiar el aspecto de una celda de una QTableView al pasar el ratón por encima?

Tags: c++, qt

Estoy intentando hacer una tabla en la que las celdas de una de sus columnas sea editable solamente a través de un cuadro de diálogo que se abrirá al pulsar un botón que haya en ella. Además, dicho botón me gustaría que sólo fuera visible cuando el ratón pase por encima de esa celda.

Leyendo acerca de ello, parece que la idea de insertar un widget personalizado es posible pero penaliza el rendimiento (según comentarios en SO en inglés) y no es la vía adecuada. Esto sale en la documentación:

> The items shown in a table view, like those in the other item views,
>   are rendered and edited using standard delegates. However, for some
>   tasks it is sometimes useful to be able to insert widgets in a table
>   instead. Widgets are set for particular indexes with the
>   setIndexWidget() function, and later retrieved with indexWidget().

Así que la vía más "natural" es a través de delegados.
Tengo este fragmento de código (copiado integramente de [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777637/adding-button-to-qtableview)) que propone usar el método

```
void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const;
```

Para dibujar el botón, y

```
bool editorEvent(QEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index)
```

Para que responda al click del ratón. 
De esta forma (mi implementación):

```
void DelegadoFormulasMedicion::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
    if (index.isValid())
    {
        QStyleOptionButton boton;
        QRect r = option.rect;//getting the rect of the cell
        int x,y,w,h;
        w = m_ancho_boton;
        h = r.height();//button height
        x = r.left() + r.width() - w;//the X coordinate
        y = r.top();//the Y coordinate
        boton.rect = QRect(x,y,w,h);
        boton.text = "...";
        boton.state = QStyle::State_MouseOver;
        QApplication::style()->drawControl( QStyle::CE_PushButton, &boton, painter);
    }
    else
    {
        DelegadoBase::paint(painter, option, index);
    }
}
```

y

```
bool DelegadoFormulasMedicion::editorEvent(QEvent *event, QAbstractItemModel *model, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index)
{
    if( event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease )
    {
        QMouseEvent * e = (QMouseEvent *)event;        
        int clickX = e->x();
        int clickY = e->y();

        QRect r = option.rect;//getting the rect of the cell
        int x,y,w,h;
        x = r.left() + r.width() - m_ancho_boton;//the X coordinate
        y = r.top();//the Y coordinate
        w = m_ancho_boton;//button width
        h = r.height();//button height

        if( clickX > x && clickX < x + w )
            if( clickY > y && clickY < y + h )
            {
                qDebug()<<"Abro dialogo";//aqui va mi dialogo
            }
        return true;
    }
    return false;    
}
```

Hasta aquí no parece haber problemas. Ahora me queda que este botón se dibuje si el ratón está sobre la celda, para lo cual entiendo que he de capturar el evento.

Para ello estaba siguiendo [estos pasos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111075/how-to-highlight-the-entire-row-on-mouse-hover-in-qtablewidget-qt5).

1.- Crear una señal en la tabla:

```
signals:
    void hoverIndexChanged(bool dentro);
```

2.- Habilitar esto en el constructor de la tabla:

```
setMouseTracking(true);
setAttribute(Qt::WA_Hover);
```

3.- Capturar la posición del ratón

```
void TablaMed::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    QPoint pos = event->pos();
    QModelIndex index = indexAt(pos);
    if (index.isValid())
    {
        if (index.column() == tipoColumnaTMedCert::FORMULA)
        {
            //qDebug()<<"Estoy dentro";
            emit hoverIndexChanged(true);
        }
        else
        {
            //qDebug()<<"Estoy fuera";
            emit hoverIndexChanged(false);
        }
    }
    TablaBase::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

4.- Conectar la señal y el slot:

```
connect(this,SIGNAL(hoverIndexChanged(bool)),dlgFM,SLOT(onHoverIndexChanged(bool)));
```

De esta forma podría cambiar un miembro bool del delegado de forma que con las pertinentes modificaciones en el método paint() mostrado anteriormente dicho botón se mostraría o no, pero no soy capaz de recoger esa señal en el delegado.

**Actualización**

Lo anteriormente expuesto funciona, solo que había olvidado poner la macro Q_OBJECT en el delegado

Acabo de poner un ejemplo completo de la tabla (muy mínimo) en pastebin, con el código suministrado por @eferion y el de arriba. No sabría decir si hay alguno más apropiado que el otro.

[Solución basada en el código de arriba](https://pastebin.com/vVfuNQQP)

[Ejemplo completo de la solución proporcionada por @eferion](https://pastebin.com/NbGaH5Dy)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes conseguir ese efecto facilmente tirando del filtro de eventos:

```
class MyEventFilter
  : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT

public:
  MyEventFilter(QTableView* table, QObject* parent)
    : QObject(parent)
    , table(table)
    , button(new QPushButton(table))
  {
    button->setText("H");
    button->setFixedSize(20, 20);
    button->setVisible(false);

    table->installEventFilter(this);
    table->setAttribute(Qt::WA_Hover);

    connect(button, SIGNAL(clicked()), SLOT(button_clicked()));
  }

private:

  QTableView* table;
  QPushButton * button;
  QModelIndex currentIndex;

  bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) override
  {
    if( event->type() == QEvent::HoverMove)
    {
      QHoverEvent * hoverEvent = static_cast<QHoverEvent*>(event);
      QPoint pos = table->viewport()->mapFromParent(hoverEvent->pos());

      currentIndex = table->indexAt(pos);

      button->setVisible(currentIndex.isValid() && currentIndex.column() == 1);

      if( button->isVisible() )
      {
        QRect rect = table->visualRect(currentIndex);
        QPoint point = rect.topRight();
        point.setX(point.x() - button->width());
        button->move(table->viewport()->mapToParent(point));
      }

      event->accept();
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }

private slots:

  void button_clicked()
  {
    auto text = QString("Celda seleccionada: (%1,%2)")
                     .arg(currentIndex.row())
                     .arg(currentIndex.column());
    QMessageBox::information(nullptr, "Celda seleccionada", text);
  }
};
```

La lógica es extremadamente simple:

Se añade un botón como hijo de la tabla, esto se hace así para que el mismo se pinte usando el viewport de la propia tabla, lo que garantiza que el botón se pinta **siempre** encima de la tabla:

```
button(new QPushButton(table))
```

Seguidamente nuestro objeto se instala como filtro de eventos de la tabla y la configura para que se gestionen los eventos de movimiento del ratón.

```
table->installEventFilter(this);
table->setAttribute(Qt::WA_Hover);
```

El objeto recibe entonces los eventos que se generen en la tabla. En este caso presta atención únicamente a los referentes a movimientos del ratón.

```
if( event->type() == QEvent::HoverMove)
```

Ante este evento pregunta a la tabla para saber cual es la celda sobre la que se encuentra el ratón

```
QHoverEvent * hoverEvent = static_cast<QHoverEvent*>(event);
QPoint pos = table->viewport()->mapFromParent(hoverEvent->pos());

QModelIndex currentIndex = table->indexAt(pos);
```

Nota que es necesario convertir las coordenadas del evento. En este caso `QTableView` usa un `viewport` para las cabeceras de las filas, otro para las de las columnas y otro para las celdas. Nosotros necesitamos conocer las coordendas dentro del viewport de las celdas.

Pues bien, si resulta que el `index` devuelto es válido y encima pertenece a la columna 1 entonces posicionamos el ratón a la derecha de la celda. Para hacer esto obtenemos el área de la celda.

```
button->setVisible(currentIndex.isValid() && currentIndex.column() == 1);

if( button->isVisible() )
{
  QRect rect = table->visualRect(currentIndex;
  QPoint point = rect.topRight();
  point.setX(point.x() - button->width());
  button->move(table->viewport()->mapToParent(point));
}
```

Inicializar este objeto es trivial:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
  ui->setupUi(this);

  auto filter = new MyEventFilter(ui->tableView, this);
}
```

Comment: Hola: Me ha costado entender que el delegado actúe como un filtro. Llevo todo el día examinando el código que me pusiste, y tiene su miga. como la forma en que se crea cada boton sobre cada celda aprovechando que (entiendo) cada delegado se crea sobre cada una de ellas. Como parte débil, no sé cómo hacer que esa funcionalidad actúe sobre una columna concreta, salvo que -no lo he probado porque se me acaba de ocurrir- se llame a ese delegado con la funcion setItemDelegateForColumn. Por otro lado, el código queda más limpio.

Comment: @user3733164 la solución no usa delegados sino un filtro de eventos. Y solo se crea un botón, que se mueve de celda en celda siguiendo al ratón.

Comment: Y he actualizado el código principal... en ese código no estaba la selección de columna activada

Comment: Cierto. Es un filtro de eventos sin más. Me confundí al ver que aparece QStyledItemDelegate en el constructor....que por cierto, sigo sin entender el por qué de construir así el filtro y no llamando directamente a QObject. Por lo demás, como siempre, muchas gracias por una respuesta tan completa y de la que siempre saco más información de la que estrictamente resuelve mi problema ;-)

Comment: @user3733164 eso ha sido un gazapo. Al copiar y pegar la solución debí de coger los fuentes de la versión incorrecta. En seguida lo arreglo. Gracias

Comment: Je je...ahora mucho más claro. Me volvía loco ese constructor. Voy a actualizar también los ejemplos :)