# ¿Se pueden seleccionar celdas en una QTableView si empiezo pulsando sobre un widget situado sobre una de ellas?

Tags: c++, qt

A ver si en el cuerpo del mensaje consigo ser más conciso.
Esta duda viene a raíz de un intento de mejorar la solución planteada [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/264451/como-cambiar-el-aspecto-de-una-celda-de-una-qtableview-al-pasar-el-rat%C3%B3n-por-en)

En resumen se trata de dotar a una tabla de un comportamiento similar a una hoja de cálculo, esto es, que en la celda actual aparezca una pequeña marca de forma que al hacer drag and drop sobre ella el comportamiento de la tabla sea diferente y se ejecute una acción. En el enlace antes puesto llego a una solución muy farragosa, y estaba intentando mejorarla.

La principal mejora es que la marca que tiene que aparecer sea un widget, y no un dibujo de la propia tabla. Esto me permite manejar señales y funciones propias lo que hace el código más legible y lógico. Pero el problema es que cuando quiero iniciar el arrastre desde ese punto, al estar realmente sobre el widget y no sobre la celda, no puedo ejecutar una selección.

Y mi pregunta es si inicio un arrastre con el ratón, pero cuando estoy situado sobre un widget sobre una celda, hay alguna forma de transmitir ese movimiento del ratón a la tabla que subyace sobre el widget.

**Actualización**

No sé si es el método a seguir, pero lo que intento es que el widget sobre la tabla (la marca) no acepte eventos del ratón y lo propague directamente al padre, mediante la función `ignore()`, pero no parece funcionar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como bien dije, este tema viene de atrás, con dudas muy [similares](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/267535/como-cambiar-el-comportamiento-del-rat%C3%B3n-sobre-una-tabla-seg%C3%BAn-la-zona-en-la-qu) aunque no exactamente [iguales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/264451/como-cambiar-el-aspecto-de-una-celda-de-una-qtableview-al-pasar-el-rat%C3%B3n-por-en).

Si bien la duda estaba resuelta de varias formas (más o menos afortunadas), ninguna de ellas me satisfacía. Por resumir, lo que quiero es que la tabla tenga un comportamiento similar a una hoja de cálculo, de forma que sobre la celda activa aparezca una pequeña marca, la cual se podrá arrastrar y en esa acción, todas las celdas seleccionadas de esa forma, se modifiquen de alguna manera concreta.

He de decir que la respuesta estaba prácticamente resuelta en el segundo enlace. Todo era cuestión de adaptar la solución propuesta por `@eferion` en dicho enlace. Y, sobre todo, de entender que la forma correcta de hacer las cosas es no tocar la tabla sino el filtro de eventos, de forma que una misma tabla actuará a las entradas de teclado/ratón/etc de una u otra forma según sea ese filtro.

De otra forma, si tengo que modificar la tabla para que responda de diferente forma a los eventos, la condeno a que no sirva para otra ocasión u otra forma de acceder a ella o manipularla, y eso en definitiva es una mala práctica.

Dicho todo esto, muestro la solución que finalmente doy por buena:

Por un lado, creo dos sencillos widgets, uno será el marco de selección *restringida*, y el otro la marca que aparecerá en la parte inferior derecha de la celda activa (están creados en el mismo fichero):

**fichero.h**

```
#ifndef MARCA_H
#define MARCA_H

#include <QWidget>

class QRect;

//********Marca***************//

class Marca : public QWidget
{
public:
    explicit Marca(int tam = 5, QWidget *parent = nullptr);
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override;

private:
    int m_tamLado;
};

//********Marco***************//

class Marco : public QWidget
{
public:
    explicit Marco(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
protected:
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *) override;
};

#endif // MARCA_H
```

**fichero.cpp**

```
#include "marca.h"
#include <QPainter>
#include <QRect>

//****************Marca*****************/

Marca::Marca(int tam, QWidget *parent) : m_tamLado(tam), QWidget(parent)
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);
}

void Marca::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    QPen pen;
    pen.setWidth(m_tamLado);
    pen.setColor(QColor(Qt::black));
    p.setPen(pen);
    p.drawRect(rect().x()+rect().width()-m_tamLado,
               rect().y()+rect().height()-m_tamLado,
               rect().x()+rect().width(),
               rect().y()+rect().height());
}


//****************Marco*****************/

Marco::Marco(QWidget *parent) : QWidget(parent)
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);
}

void Marco::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)
{
    QPainter p(this);
    QPen pen;
    pen.setWidth(4);
    pen.setColor(QColor(Qt::black));
    p.setPen(pen);
    //p.drawRect(rect());
    p.drawLine(rect().topLeft(),rect().bottomLeft());
    p.drawLine(rect().topLeft(),rect().topRight());
    pen.setWidth(1);
    pen.setColor(QColor(Qt::gray));
    p.setPen(pen);
    p.drawLine(rect().topRight(),rect().bottomRight());
    p.drawLine(rect().bottomLeft(),rect().bottomRight());
}
```

Y ahora el filtro de eventos:

**myeventfilter.h**

```
#ifndef MYEVENTFILTER_H
#define MYEVENTFILTER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QModelIndex>
#include <QItemSelection>
#include <QRect>

class MiTabla;
class QPushButton;
class Marca;
class Marco;


class MyEventFilter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyEventFilter(MiTabla* table, QObject* parent=nullptr);
    bool eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event) override;
    QRect DibujarMarcasSeleccionRestringida();

private slots:
    void FiltrarColumnaSeleccion();

private:
    MiTabla* m_tabla;
    Marca* m_marca;
    Marco* m_marcoSeleccionRestringida;
    QModelIndex m_currentIndex;
    bool m_modoRestringido;
    int m_tamMarca;
    bool m_botonPulsado;
};

#endif // MYEVENTFILTER_H
```

**myeventfilter.cpp**

```
#include "myeventfilter.h"
#include "./mitabla.h"
#include "./marca.h"
#include <QModelIndex>
#include <QEvent>
#include <QHoverEvent>
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QDebug>

MyEventFilter::MyEventFilter(MiTabla *table, QObject* parent): QObject(parent),m_tabla(table)
{
    m_modoRestringido = false;
    m_tamMarca = 5;
    table->installEventFilter(this);
    table->setAttribute(Qt::WA_Hover);
    m_marca = new Marca(5,table->viewport());
    m_marca->setVisible(false);
    m_marcoSeleccionRestringida = new Marco(table->viewport());
    m_marcoSeleccionRestringida->setVisible(false);
    m_botonPulsado = false;

    QObject::connect(m_tabla->selectionModel(),SIGNAL(selectionChanged(QItemSelection,QItemSelection)),this,SLOT(FiltrarColumnaSeleccion()));

}

bool MyEventFilter::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    QPoint pos;
    if( event->type() == QEvent::HoverMove)
    {
        QHoverEvent * hoverEvent = static_cast<QHoverEvent*>(event);
        pos = m_tabla->viewport()->mapFromParent(hoverEvent->pos());
        //qDebug()<<"hover pos "<<pos;
        if (m_modoRestringido == false)
        {
            m_currentIndex = m_tabla->indexAt(pos);
        }
        //si hay alguna celda seleccionada y es la actual
        if (m_tabla->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes().size()>0 && m_currentIndex == m_tabla->currentIndex())
        {
            //obtengo el rectangulo que abarca desde la primera hasta la ultima celda seleccionada
            DibujarMarcasSeleccionRestringida();
            m_marca->setVisible(true);

            QPoint point = DibujarMarcasSeleccionRestringida().bottomRight();

            if (pos.x()>point.x()-m_tamMarca &&
                    pos.x()<point.x() &&
                    pos.y()>point.y()-m_tamMarca &&
                    pos.y()<point.y()
                    )
            {
                m_marcoSeleccionRestringida->setVisible(true);
                m_tabla->setCursor(Qt::CrossCursor);
                m_modoRestringido = true;
            }
            else
            {
                if (m_botonPulsado == false)
                {
                    m_marcoSeleccionRestringida->setVisible(false);
                    m_tabla->setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
                    m_modoRestringido = false;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            m_marca->setVisible(false);
        }
        return true;
    }

    else if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        m_botonPulsado = true;        
        return false;
    }
    else if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease)
    {
        m_botonPulsado = false;
        m_tabla->setCursor(Qt::ArrowCursor);
        m_currentIndex = m_tabla->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes().last();
        m_tabla->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes().clear();
        //si estoy en modo restringido efectuo una accion al soltar el boton del raton
        if (m_modoRestringido == true)
        {
            qDebug()<<"Funcion para hacer algo con los indices:";
            for (const QModelIndex& i : m_tabla->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes())
            {
                qDebug()<<i;
            }
        }
        m_modoRestringido = false;
        return false;
    }
    return QObject::eventFilter(obj,event);
}

QRect MyEventFilter::DibujarMarcasSeleccionRestringida()
{
    QRect rectSelect = m_tabla->visualRect(m_tabla->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes().first())|
            m_tabla->visualRect(m_tabla->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes().last());
    m_marca->move(rectSelect.topLeft());
    m_marca->resize(rectSelect.size());
    m_marcoSeleccionRestringida->move(rectSelect.topLeft());
    m_marcoSeleccionRestringida->resize(rectSelect.size());
    return rectSelect;

}

void MyEventFilter::FiltrarColumnaSeleccion()
{
    if (m_modoRestringido == true && !m_tabla->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes().isEmpty())
    {
        for(const QModelIndex& item : m_tabla->selectionModel()->selectedIndexes())
        {
            if( item.column() != m_currentIndex.column())
            {
                m_tabla->selectionModel()->select(item,QItemSelectionModel::Deselect);
            }
        }
        DibujarMarcasSeleccionRestringida();
    }
}
```

Ya solo queda instalar el filtro de eventos en el viewport() de la tabla. Aquí el constructor:

```
MiTabla::MiTabla(QWidget *parent):QTableView(parent)
{
    setModel((new MiModelo(this)));
    viewport()->installEventFilter(new MyEventFilter(this));
}
```

Y ya está. De esta forma no se toca la tabla. Básicamente lo que hace -en este caso concreto- es forzar a que sólo se seleccionen celdas bajo la celda primera, y que cuando se termine esa selección, se ejecute una acción sobre ellas.

El código, si bien es algo farragoso, es bastante autoexplicativo.